# Nested indexing in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

I have a python dict, and some (but not all) of its values are also dicts.

For example:

```
    d = {'a' : 1,
         'b' : {'c' : 3, 'd' : 'target_value'}
        }
```

What would be the best way to pass in keys to reach any target value?  Something like `retrieve(d, (key, nested_key, ...))` where `retrieve(d, ('b','d'))` would return `target value`.

Comment: Where are you getting the crazy data structure from?

Comment: I am parsing a file and organizing it into dictionaries which are sometimes nested.  But this applies to any nested indexable data structures.

Comment: My mistake, `retrieve(d, ('b', 'd'))` should return `target_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better option here is to find a way to normalize your data structure, but if you can't for some reason, you can just access each key in order.

For example:

```
def nested_getter(dictionary, *keys):
    val = dictionary[keys[0]]
    for key in keys[1:]:
        val = val[key]
    return val
d = {'a' : 1,
     'b' : {'c' : 3, 'd' : 'target_value'}
    }
print(nested_getter(d, 'b', 'd'))
```

You could also do it recursively:

```
def nested_getter(dictionary, *keys):
    val = dictionary[keys[0]]
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        return nested_getter(val, *keys[1:])
    else:
        return val
```